# How to get HTML tags from object value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm creating a react app and getting my data from an object.
How can I make the string tages in body of object to be worked properly.

The object is something like this

```
    const info = [{
        "title": "More Information",
        "body": "<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>",
        }]
```

While my react code is something like this

```
 const Page = ({ info }) => {
    return (
        <div>
           <div>{info.title}</div>
           <div>{info.body}</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: hello, @goldenOtter, you mean when info data don't exist, you want it don't appear the b and p tag?

Comment: hello, Can you explain more?

Comment: when I access the info[0].body data, the p and b tags show up on the page. I want a way to display the body value and have the p and b tags create separate paragraphs and bold text like they're supposed to

Answer (score 0):

> By default, React DOM escapes any values embedded in JSX before rendering them. Thus it ensures that you can never inject anything that’s not explicitly written in your application. Everything is converted to a string before being rendered. This helps prevent XSS (cross-site-scripting) attacks.
> [Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks)

##### Update `body` into a JSX (if possible)

*NOTE: Also, `info` is an array whose first element is an object with `title` and `body`, so you can't directly access the object.*

```js
const Foo = () => {
  const info = [
    {
      title: "More Information",
      body: <p><b>Hello World!!</b></p>,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{info[0].title}</div>
      <div>{info[0].body}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

##### If you can't change `body` to JSX, you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

*Note: Use this approach with caution & sanitize the html string if required.*

```js
const Foo = () => {
  const info = [
    {
      title: "More Information",
      body: "<p><b>Hello World!!</b></p>",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{info[0].title}</div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: info[0].body}}/>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @goldenOtter Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I have the info array in another file so when I try to turn it into a jsx element, it just says unexpected token '<'. Also I'm mapping the Page component in another component and that's how I'm accessing the individual elements in the object.

Comment: @goldenOtter I've updated my answer please take a look and do let me know if you have any further issues.